# codeigniter Query Bindings and Boolean Full-Text Searches

Tags: codeigniter, binding, boolean

What i need is to execute this query (MYISAM)

```
$sql = "SELECT      EventName 
        FROM        adds_table_events 
        WHERE       MATCH (EventName) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        ORDER BY    EventDate asc 
        LIMIT 4

return $this->db->query($sql, array($name));
```

and what i need to find all the matches equal to "some text".

For example my correct result must be:

"i am a some text that" , correct
"some text its ok" , correct
"some not text", incorrect
"more things some text" , correct

but i get:

"i am a some text that" , correct
"other **text** its ok" , **CORRECT**
"some not text", **CORRECT**
"more things **some** tree", **CORRECT**

When in read this documentation from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html it says:

'"some words"'

Find rows that contain the exact phrase “some words” (for example, rows that contain “some words of wisdom” but not “some noise words”). Note that the “"” characters that enclose the phrase are operator characters that delimit the phrase. They are not the quotation marks that enclose the search string itself.

But i dont know how to use the “"” characters

thanks!

Comment: This is working for me:      AND   MATCH (EventName) AGAINST ('\"" . $name . "\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE), but i would like use "?" for security

Comment: this is not working for me:  AND   MATCH (EventName) AGAINST ('\"?\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) :(